# How to Implement Newey-West covariance matrix properly for MDE estimation

Tags: estimation, covariance-matrix, garch, neweywest

I am trying to implement the MDE method for GARCH given by [Baillie and Chung '01](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bkg_qq7-PNya378zP5pQ0F88zZeZZOAo/view?usp=sharing) (*Estimation of GARCH Models from the Autocorrelations of the Squares of a Process*, Jrl. of Time Series Analysis) but I can't understand it enough to implement the algorithm.

For a squared process $X \sim GARCH(\theta)$ with size $n$, MDE criterion is

$$\arg\min_\theta \left(R C^{-1}_{NW}R'\right)\tag1$$

where R equals to $\hat\rho - \rho(\theta) $ with $\hat\rho$ as sample autocorrelations and $\rho(\theta)$ as parametric autocorrelation function for GARCH process. And the $C_{NW}$ is the Newey-West Covariance matrix:

$$C_{NW} = \gamma_0^{-2} S\tag2$$

Here

$$S=\Omega_0 + \sum_{i=1}^m \left(1- \frac{i}{1+m}\right) \left(\Omega_i+\Omega_i'\right)\tag3$$

with $$\Omega_i= \frac{\sum_{t=i+1}^n Z_t Z_{t-i}'}{n}\tag4$$

And for $D=x-\bar{x}$

$$
Z_t = \begin{bmatrix} 
D_t \, D_{t-1} - \rho_1(\theta)\,D_t^2\\
\vdots\\ 
D_t \, D_{t-k} - \rho_k(\theta)\,D_t^2 
\end{bmatrix}\tag5$$

The value $m$ is the number of positive autocorrelations and for simplicity lets say $k=5$.  $Z_t$ and $\rho$ are $k\times 1$ vectors,  $\Omega$ and $S$ are $k\times k$ matrices.

I implemented the Eq.5 as follows

```Python
#--------------------------------------------------------
# for Eq. 5
# as a (k x k) Z matrix containing Z_1 to Z_k
z = np.zeros((k, k), np.float64)   
t=0
while t<k:
    i = t+1
    z[t] = D[t]*D[i:k+i]-rho[:k]*D[t]**2
    t = i
#----------------------------------------------------
```

I am not sure if this is correct way to build $Z$ (mathematically it is correct for $Z_t$, but what about $Z_{t-i}$?), and since $k$, $m$ and $n$ are not equal, I am confused about Eq. 3 and 4. So can someone help me and clearify things?

Comment: Hi: I only slightly more than glanced at the paper but $k$ is the dimension of each $Z_t$ observation, $m$ is the number of lags you want to use when calculating the newey west  estimator ( this is subjective. see the original NW paper for details ) and $n$ is the number of $Z_t$ observations in the sample. So, one would not necessarily expect the value of these parameters to be the same.

Comment: This paper below has some suggestions for how to deal with the choice of $m$. Notice that your problem is not totally standard Newey West because, usually, NW uses autocorrelations ($\rho_j$  are scalars in the paper below ) for the NW estimate. In your case, you have COVARIANCE MATRICES that need to be used for the estimate. So, Baillie and Chung are kind of doing an extension of Newey West or, if you don't want to call it an extension, it's an application of Newey West to the multivariate case.

Comment: http://econweb.umd.edu/~chao/Teaching/Econ423/Econ423_HAC_Estimation.pdf

Comment: Thanks. Yes, $n$ here is the observation size but $Z_t$ ($k\times1$) is not a priori. So I am confused about how to calculate $Z_t$ for $t>(n-k)$ for Eq.4  and so on.

Comment: I'm sorry Erdem but I don't know what "$Z_t$ is not a priori" means. I thought $Z_t$ represented an observation so should there not be $n$ of them ?

Comment: Sorry, I ment it should be calculated by the given observations, $Z_t$ is not an observation itself. As I understand the maximum size is $n-k$ but idk. I only assume it shouldn't be that large. Because the memory needs would be huge for the big data.

Comment: HI Erdem: Three things. 1) I'll try to read the whole paper during this week because it really needs to be read completely and carefully. 2) I'm not sure how long 1) will take me ?  3) Even when I read it, I don't know if I'll be able to say anything helpful ? Maybe someone else on this list who works in this area can look at it and say something helpful ?  I haven't worked with NW so thanks to anyone else who can help. I'll get back to you either way.

Comment: Hi Erdem: I'm not finished but I've been reading the paper slowly. My only question right now is: "What are you trying to do exactly ?". My guess is that you want to replicate something in the paper but they do so many different simulations and calcs that I'm wondering what part are you trying to replicate. They also tend to just throw expressions out there so sometimes I try to find out how the expression came about but not always successfully. Thanks for more details.

Comment: Hi. My main pupose is to model highly autocorrelated errors using a better tool than MLE (My experience with real data put me in this direction which was frustrating). So i've researched and found this paper which seems like a wonderful solution to me.  Because the estimation is implemented directly on the autocorrelations. Plus, there is the Newey-West covariance matrix (a proven correction tool for autocorrelated samples). Baillie and Chung simulated this in 4.2 (Monte Carlo results for GARCH(1, 1) with leptokurtic errors). This one I am trying to replicate.

Comment: BTW. I implemented the estimation with bartlett's formula using sample autocorrelations. it gives satisfying results. This one, on the other hand, I am still trying to understand.

Comment: Hi Erdem: yes, the bartlett sample autocorrelation formula that looks confusing is actually not all that confusing when you apply it so specific models. It only looks confusing because of the summation from 1 to infinity. but, for specific models, the sum is a lot less. I'm still reading but I'm glad you are making some progress. I always wanted to learn more about GMM concept and using autocorrelations for robustness also so I'm going to keep going at my snail's pace.

Comment: @ErdemŞen I see your request for migration but this question seems to be answered by yourself. What would you expect to gain from moving it to Stats?

Comment: @Bob Jansen let's see. I first tried to ask this question on this community but it was closed (the reason was "it is about programming"). As i was new in the community i thought it is not allowed, so i reedit a bit and searched another related community. I found finance... I waited an answer for 2 weeks and i researched at the same time to solve it. then i answered. later i learnt that it was my misunderstanding and it could be published here with some small edits. i have no knowledge on finance and i see my self more a statistician... so, here, CV is home to this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution using a heuristic way. As mentioned in the comments obove, the size of the sum in ($4$) seems a bit problematic. After analysing the results, I took the upper bound of the sum as $n-k$ (Since $Z_t$ is $k\times1$, using ($4$) as it is, returns `errors`)

For the size of Bartlett's weights ($m$), i used $m=k$ (It was a personal choice, I decided by comparing this with the results of the formulas suggested in the literature)

The working codes of the implementation for GARCH process is shared below:

```python
# MDE Newey-West
#----------------------------------------------------
#----------------------------------------------------
k=30                                        # Zt-size
k1= k+1
m = 30                   # size of Bartlett's weights               
m1= m+1
#----------------------------------------------------
_x = x[::-1]               # for timeserries indexing
#---------------------------------------------------- 
scor = acf(_x, nlags=nobs)  # sample autocorrelations
#----------------------------------------------------
D = _x - x.mean()
#----------------------------------------------------
w = 1 - np.arange(m1)/(m1)       # Bartlett's weights
#====================================================
@jit
def MDE_NW(param) -> float:
    #------------------------------------------------
    a, b = param
    atb = a+b
    ab = a*b
    #------------------------------------------------
    if (a <= 0.0) or (b <= 0.0) or (1-atb <= 0): 
        return 1e12
    #------------------------------------------------
    # parametric autocorrelations
    ro = np.zeros(k1)
    ro[1] = a + (ab*a) / (1 - 2*ab - b**2)
    i=2
    while i<m:
        ro[i] = ro[1] * (atb)**(i-1)
        i+=1
    pcor = ro[1:]
    #------------------------------------------------
    # Z matrix (here as h)
    h = np.zeros((nobs-k, k))
    t=0
    while t<nobs-k:
        i = t+1
        h[t] = D[t]*D[i:k+i]-pcor*D[t]**2
        t = i
    #------------------------------------------------
    R  = scor[1:k1]-pcor
    #------------------------------------------------
    # https://www.statsmodels.org/0.6.1/_modules/statsmodels/stats/sandwich_covariance.html#:~:text=S_hac_simple
    S = dot(h.T, h)
    i=1
    while i<m1:   # m+1
        omg = dot(h[i:].T, h[:-i])
        S += w[i] * (omg + omg.T)
        i+=1
    return R.T @ inv(S) @ R
```

One can implement this function using `scipy.optimize.minimize` (`BFGS` and `Nelder-Mead` algorithms are suggested. BFGS is faster and mostly better but sometimes returns wrong values)

Comment: Thanks Erdem. I'll check it out and hopefully learn something. I'm still going through the paper ( sllllllllllllooooooooooooooooooooooowly ).